# When new user added to group, email alert sending?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

There is an email sending when new user added to site groups. It is sending custom email format **"A new user had been added to XXX Section group of the Communities, the user's name is Matthew .  The Member # of the user is 3493100".** I don't understand how this is happen. Our customer center and sharepoint admin only getting these emails. Now they want to their id from emails sending list. I think my previous colleague written this task.

How can I find this program or feature or event to remove email id? Please need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it you have automatic group access turned on.

You can disable it by going to the group:

Site Actions -> Site Settings -> People and groups -> Select the group -> Settings -> Group Settings

Then under "Membership Requests" turn off auto accept requests, or clear the email.

The other option is to remove the access request email

Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site permissions -> Manage access requests

Remove the email or the options from the menu

Answer (score 0):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288540(office.12).aspx

> Manage alerts On the Site Settings
>   page for the Web site, under
>   Administration, click Go to Site
>   Administration.
>
> Under Management and Statistics, click
>   Manage user alerts.
>
> On the Manage User Alerts page, select
>   a user name in the Display alerts for
>   *_* box, and then click Update.
>
> To delete an alert, select the check
>   box next to the alert, and then click
>   Delete Selected Alerts.

Answer (score 0):

See the group setting of the group where you are adding new users?

There must be checked the option of sending emails when user will be added.

Answer (score 0):

I have dll that running when ever user added to groups. I removed email id from there.